# Phase portrait of $(c_1e^t+c_2te^t,c_2e^t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

I solved the system $x'=Ax,$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1  \\
        0 & 1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ but I don't know how to sketch the phase portrait for it.

The solution is $(x,y)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))=(c_1e^t+c_2te^t,c_2e^t).$

I tried to eliminate the parameter

From $y$, $e^t=(1/c_2)y$. Making the substitution in $x$, I have that $x=c_3y+ty=y(c_3+t).$ As you can see $t$ didn't eliminate.

What can I do from here?

Comment: Please reread the **definition** of the phase portrait, this should show you that it does not involve the solution of the system (hence the computations you present are offtopic) and that the task of drawing it is not Herculean in the present case.

Comment: You can do an online search for "phase plane plotters"  or "phase plane online", or something similar. There are lots of online tools available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have computed the solution correctly. Now, let us assume the initial condition $x(0)=x_0, y(0)=y_0$. Then the solution is

$$(x,y)=(x_0e^t+y_0te^t, y_0e^t).$$

Now, we want to eliminate $t$. We have $t = \ln (\tfrac{y}{y_0})$ and hence

$$x=\bigg(\frac{x_0}{y_0}+\ln \big(\frac{y}{y_0}\big)\bigg) y.$$

We can easily plot $x$ as a function of $y$, which yields the phase portrait

[image]

Of course, you wouldn't need to compute the solution directly for a phase portrait even though it is a practical method. Alternatively just plug a point into the ODE and follow the orbit to see the dynamics of the ODE. For example let's take $(\varepsilon,0)$ into the ODE. Then we have $\dot x= \varepsilon>0$ and $\dot y=0$. Hence the orbit is moving along the axis into the direction of increasing $x$.

Comment: Sorry but a phase portrait is not the representation of the solutions.

Comment: @Did according to my definition a phase portrait is the representation of the solutions with the arrows to indicate the direction of movement. What's your definition?

Comment: The same without the solutions. If one adds the solutions to a phase portrait, one gets a diagram of the solutions.