# Does it look like the correct 3D phase portrait?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, vector-fields

What I am talking about: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space

You can test it by yourself in my site(I have made it on three.js),you can move it and scale

https://imaimachi.sumy.ua/levels

---

I have a system of kinetic equations:

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}= 2x+32-z $$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}= 5y+x+17 $$
$$\dfrac{dz}{dt}= 6x-2z+19y $$

And I had an idea to build a phase portrait of it. I made it using isoclines method. I found isocline equations for each angle from 1 to 360 degrees. I drawn it using three js in browser.

What did I get:

[image]

I have never done a 3D phase portraits and actually never worked with 3D graphics.

So, does it look like the correct phase portrait for this system?

**Update. What are the steps literally:**

I make a system

$$\dfrac{dz}{dx}= \dfrac{6x-2z+19y}{2x+32-z} $$
$$\dfrac{dz}{dy}= \dfrac{6x-2z+19y}{5y+x+17} $$

Equals constant for each angle:

$$\dfrac{6x-2z+19y}{2x+32-z} = tg \alpha $$
$$\dfrac{6x-2z+19y}{5y+x+17} = tg \alpha $$

For each $\alpha$ from 1 to 360 I get solution for this system in form

$$y=a(b*x+c)$$
$$z=d(e*x+h)$$

And then draw the isocline parametric equation $(x,\space a(b*x+c),\space d(e*x+h))$

**Update 2. The second test**

I have drawn a phase portrait for this system

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}= 5y+3 $$
$$\dfrac{dy}{dt}= x+16y-z-9 $$
$$\dfrac{dz}{dt}= 12x-18y+z $$

Phase portrait

[image]

At this time it looks like of the type of equilibrium point 
[image]

But the problem is that the system has only one equilibrium point $x=\dfrac{3}{5},\space y=-\dfrac{3}{5},\space z=-18$. In the graph I made it seems like (0,0,0)

Answer (score 1):

A general methodology for such systems :

Write your differential system under the form:

$$V'=AV+B \tag 1 $$

for an appropriate matrix $A$ and vector $B$.

The RHS is affine. Transform it into a linear system :

$$W'=AW \ \ \text{where} \ \ W:=V-V_0$$

by substracting to (1) equation :

$$0=AV_0+B$$

[Such a constant vector $V_0$ exists due to the invertibility of $A$] .

then express $W$ in the form of the exponential of a matrix applied to a vector :

$$W=\exp(tA) W_{ini}$$

where $W_{ini}$ is obtained through initial conditions, finally giving :

> $$V=\exp(tA)(V_{ini}-V_0)+V_0$$

(of course : $V_{ini}$ are initial conditions on $V$).

Numerical application :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 &0 &-1\\1& 5 &0\\6&19& -2\end{pmatrix}, \ \ B=\begin{pmatrix}32\\17\\0\end{pmatrix} , \ \ V_0=\begin{pmatrix}-643/9\\98/9\\-998/9\end{pmatrix}  $$

then use a Computer Algebra System for obtaining $\exp(tA)$ using eigenvalues $    3.8920, 2.1725, -1.0644$ of $A$.

Comment: I suppose it’s kinda not the exact thing I am asked about. You explained how to solve it directly, but the phase portrait method is about getting solution by not solving the system directly

Comment: You mean obtaining a phase portrait without even solving ODE for $(x,y,z)$?

Comment: If your question is "are my isoclines the good ones", I thought you wanted to compare your figure with integral curves obtained through explicit solutions. Besides, what signification do you give to a "3D phase portrait": what are the axes for (position x, speed x', acceleration x'') ?

Comment: I just saw what you have added ; I don't see any connection with a phase portrait.

Comment: No connection? Why? Phase portrait consists of phase trajectories. Phase trajectories can be found using isoclines method. In 2D case you should solve $$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=tg\alpha $$ equation that will give a line equation in form y=f(x)

Comment: « axes for (position x, speed x', acceleration x'')» seems we are talking about different things, because phase portrait doesn’t have those axis. It has x, y, and in case of 3D z axis

Comment: It shows how one variable changes due to another variable

Comment: Then, why do you need a special representation space instead of the usual space of variables $(x,y,z)$ ? A phase space uses generalized coordinates in lagrangian terms : you don't need such a structure !

Comment: Often, in physical models, kinetic equations are too difficult to be solved. The purpose of phase portrait is to estimate the system, by not solving it directly.

Comment: My native language is not English, perhaps “phase portrait” means different stuff in English

Comment: Analytically, to make a phase portrait (2D) you find some isoclines(for 90, 0 and 45 degrees it’s easy) and then find equilibrium points and their types. There are 6 types of equilibrium points. https://imgur.com/DmapJ2J Here they are (in Russian language)

Comment: No language ambiguity about "phase space". Once again, **and I will stop there** : which generalized coordinates do you use for your axes ? As I said, I am sure that your graphic is to be interpreted in ordinary space of initial variables (x,y,z).

Comment: Yes, in my graph it x,y and z

Comment: What are You wrote in Your answer is pretty similar to determine the equilibrium point type, by the way

Comment: Yes $V_0$ should be the fixed point. But my values don"t agree with yours. I have checked my computations. Are you sure you have copied exactly the good data ?

Comment: It’s a simple system of linear equations(although with 3 variables). Hence it has only one solution. I actually just brought it to wolfram. You want say equilibrium point is not (3/5,-3/5,-18), or what? What do You mean by copied the good data?

Comment: I meant that you may have written 32 instead of 23, I don't know...

Comment: You are doubt in what? In equilibrium point, or in my graphs at all?

Comment: I just wanted you to check the initial 3 equations. I am sorry by I will stop here our exchanges.

Comment: Last remark : see the comment of (the very experienced) @Did after the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2484331)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.

The first one is exception - it’s wrong, because I rotated each part of integral curve due to z axis, instead of x, and some logics in my code was wrong.

The second one is perfectly correct, just look:

[image]

X - RED

Y - GREEN

Z - BLUE

Look at the x equation- it depends only on y, and the dependence is linear. Now look on the “2D” case of x/y to see better:

[image]

I think it’s obvious that all is correct.

So, now I can see how the system behaves, haven’t solved it directly - this is the phase portrait.

---

This is how z depends on x

[image]